# SparkSQL - how to reuse a previously selected value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need the value of the first UDF (GetOtherTriggers) as a parameter to the second UDF (GetTriggerType).

The following code is not working:

```
val df = sql.sql(
  "select GetOtherTriggers(categories) as other_triggers, GetTriggerType(other_triggers) from my_table")
```

return the following exception:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'other_triggers' given input columns: [my_table columns];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery:

```
val df = sql.sql("""select GetTriggerType(other_triggers), other_triggers 
                 from (
                      select GetOtherTriggers(categories) as other_triggers, *
                      from my_table
                      ) withOther """)
```

Test:

```
val df = sc.parallelize (1 to 10).map(x => (x, x*2, x*3)).toDF("nr1", "nr2", "nr3");
df.createOrReplaceTempView("nr");
spark.udf.register("x3UDF", (x: Integer) => x*3);
spark.sql("""select x3UDF(nr1x3), nr1x3, nr3 
             from (
                   select x3UDF(nr1) as nr1x3, * 
                   from nr
                  ) a """)
     .show()
```

Gives:

```
+----------+-----+---+
|UDF(nr1x3)|nr1x3|nr3|
+----------+-----+---+
|         9|    3|  4|
|        18|    6|  8|
|        27|    9| 12|
|        36|   12| 16|
|        45|   15| 20|
|        54|   18| 24|
|        63|   21| 28|
|        72|   24| 32|
|        81|   27| 36|
|        90|   30| 40|
+----------+-----+---+
```

Comment: What do mean by withOther? 
I get RunTimeException with "failure: end of input"

Comment: It's just an alias - as far as I know it's not mandatory, you can omit it

Comment: I've tried: val df = sql.sql("select GetTriggerType(other_triggers), other_triggers from (select GetOtherTriggers(categories) as other_triggers from my_table)").
but got RunTimeException with "failure: end of input"

Comment: same. and I need the other fields as well. it's more like:
"select ts, GetTriggerType(other_triggers), other_triggers from (select GetOtherTriggers(categories) as other_triggers, * from my_table)". so I need all my_table fields

Comment: @o_b7 Make sure you are using `"""`, 3x`"`, because it's multiline string. Delete additional enter after sql invocation

Comment: Still, the same exception.

Comment: It is very strange and probably unconnected with this question - I cannot reproduce this error with test data